# Formatting XML from PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that runs a stored procedure which returns XML. I then export the XML into a file but when I open the file, each line has 3 dots at the end and the line isn't complete. This is with using `out-file`.

When I use `Export-Clixml` the XML that is returned from the query is dumped in a tag called `<props>` which is not one of my tags.

I am unsure where to go from here to save my XML in it's original format.

The PowerShell Script that I am using is similar to this:

```
$Date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm" 
$File = "C:\Temp\MyFile"+$Date+".xml"

$Query = "exec dbo.usp_MyProc"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -database MyDatabase -ServerInstance MyServer | out-file $File -Encoding utf8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the data into XML
Try this:

```
[xml]$Result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -database MyDatabase -ServerInstance MyServer 
$Result | out-file $File -Encoding utf8
```

or this

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -database MyDatabase -ServerInstance MyServer |ConvertTo-XML |Out-File $File -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: Out-File has a width limit. See my answer.

Comment: `Out-File` doesn't render an `[xml]` instance as XML text. `ConvertTo-Xml` isn't meant to be used with XML text input.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming the XML returned from your SQL command is well formed XML, you could also push the XML string through .net's formatting (essentially a pretty printing of the XML).

```
function Format-XML {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)][string]$xmlcontent)
  $xmldoc = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
  $xmldoc.LoadXml($xmlcontent)
  $sw = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
  $writer = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextwriter($sw)
  $writer.Formatting = [System.XML.Formatting]::Indented
  $xmldoc.WriteContentTo($writer)
  $sw.ToString()
}

$Date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm" 
$File = "C:\Temp\MyFile"+$Date+".xml"

$Query = "exec dbo.usp_MyProc"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -database MyDatabase -ServerInstance MyServer `
  | Format-XML `
  | Set-Content -Path $File -Force
```

`Export-CliXml` exports PowerShell XML, including type information, that can be loaded from disk to rehydrate a variable - hence the extra information.

`Out-File` has a default width, set by the host PowerShell environment. See `Get-Help Out-File -Full`.

An example without the XML formatting, storing the DataRow result and picking out the XML column.

```
$Date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm" 
$File = "C:\Temp\MyFile"+$Date+".xml"

$Query = "exec dbo.usp_MyProc"

$resultRow = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -database MyDatabase -ServerInstance MyServer


$resultRow['XMLColumn'] | Set-Content -Path $File -Force
```

You'll obviously need to rename XMLColumn with the name of the column from your stored procedure.

Comment: I am getting an error with this " Exception calling "LoadXml" with "1" argument(s): "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, 
position 1."
At line:6 char:3
+   $xmldoc.LoadXml($xmlcontent)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException "

Comment: Sounds like your XML isn't well formed (maybe multiple root nodes?). Use the example without the function and remove the line <code>  | Format-XML `</code>

Comment: it returns each line but instead of the XML it says "System.Data.DataRow"

Comment: Sorry, thought I'd replied. Store the result in a variable, then pick out the XML data from a column in your DataRow. See amended example.

Comment: Thanks for that. This works, sort of. It only pulls out 4000 characters. I have tried adding -MaxLength to it but the Set-Content cmdlet doesn't recognise that command

Comment: Is that because of the return type of your SQL stored procedure? Maybe it's set to NVARCHAR(4000) or VARCHAR(4000). If you can change the procedure, set it to return a VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Do you know who the author of `Format-XML` is?

Comment: No, sorry, but I guess a quick Google search might help? If I need to add the source/author, please let me know. It was a code snippet I’d saved a long time ago

Answer (score 2):

```
function FormatXmlFile {
param (
    $filePath
)

$xml = Get-Content $filePath -Encoding Unicode
$xml = [xml]$xml
$Indent = 2
$StringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $StringWriter
$xmlWriter.Formatting = "indented"
$xmlWriter.Indentation = $Indent
$xml.WriteContentTo($XmlWriter)
$XmlWriter.Flush()
$StringWriter.Flush()
Set-Content -Path $filePath -Value $StringWriter.ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function pxml ($xmlfile) {
  $a = [xml](get-content $xmlfile)
  $a.save("$pwd\$xmlfile")
}
```

Comment: Your function is severely limited in that it only works with files located _in the current directory_. Also, consider adding an explanation of what your function does and why you named it that way. The `[xml] (get-content ...)` idiom is convenient, but [not fully robust](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71848130/45375). In a function, you can easily avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly nicer way if you are ok to save to console out...

```
$xml = [xml] (gc c:\temp\powershell.xml)
$xml.Save([Console]::Out)
```

Credit to [Dr. Scripto](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-display-formatted-xml-with-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

Was really happy with @TechSpud's answer above, but found that empty XML nodes got introduced line breaks.

This version removes the linebreaks from empty XML nodes (or nodes just containing spaces) using a regex replace:

```
function Format-XML {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)][string]$xmlcontent)
    $xmldoc = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
    $xmldoc.LoadXml($xmlcontent)
    $sw = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
    $writer = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextwriter($sw)
    $writer.Formatting = [System.XML.Formatting]::Indented
    $xmldoc.WriteContentTo($writer)
    $sw2 = $sw.ToString()
    $sw2 -replace '<(\w+)>[\s\r\n]*<\/\1>', "<`$1></`$1>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an in-house script, an easy and pragmatic way to format XML is to pipe it through [XML Starlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$myXmlObject.OuterXml | xml.exe format --indent-spaces 2
```

Or:

```
xml.exe format --indent-spaces 2 myXmlFile.txt
```